# How can I reuse my fragment's code?

Tags: android, fragment, refactoring, android-room, android-livedata

I'm writing an Android application with ViewPager. My ViewPager contains two Fragments. In each fragment are located two receclerViews to show different LiveData lists of items from Database (I'm using Room)

**The code for BaseFragment**

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private NewsAdapter adapter;
public ViewModel mViewModel;

public BaseFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ViewModel.class);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feeds, container, false);
    recyclerView = mView.findViewById(R.id.feeds_recycler_view);
    return mView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setUpRecyclerView();
    mViewModel.getAllNewsEntities()
            .observe(this, allNewsEntities -> {
                NewsEntityUtilCallback productDiffUtilCallback =
                        new NewsEntityUtilCallback(adapter.getNewsItems(), allNewsEntities);
                DiffUtil.DiffResult newsEntitiesDiffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(productDiffUtilCallback);
                adapter.setNewsItems(allNewsEntities);
                newsEntitiesDiffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(adapter);
            });
}

protected void setUpRecyclerView() {
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    ItemClickListener onClickListener = (v, position) -> {
        String url = adapter.getNewsItems().get(position).getLink();
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        if (browserIntent.resolveActivity(getContext().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
    };
    adapter = new NewsAdapter(getContext(), onClickListener);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

Look closely at this code section:

```
mViewModel.getAllNewsEntities()
            .observe(this, allNewsEntities -> {
                NewsEntityUtilCallback productDiffUtilCallback =
                        new NewsEntityUtilCallback(adapter.getNewsItems(), allNewsEntities);
                DiffUtil.DiffResult newsEntitiesDiffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(productDiffUtilCallback);
                adapter.setNewsItems(allNewsEntities);
                newsEntitiesDiffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(adapter);
            });
}
```

Here I'm going to observe different LiveData queries in each Fragment(in the second Fragment it's mViewModel.getAllBookmarkedNewsEntities()).The other things my code will be equals (the same lifecycles methods, the same RecyclerView). **So could give me advice about the best possible design principle to refactor my code.** I don't want simply to copy my code in another Fragment class just because of one line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just extends the BaseFragment and override onActivityCreated method. Something like this:

```
public class ReuseBaseFragment extends BaseFragment {
    @Override
   public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      //Your new code here
   }
}
```